# Process 16-bit TIFF (increase brightness)

Tags: c#, console-application, tiff

I am getting error 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' at line output.WriteScanline(scanline, i);

I want take file from one folder and after processing, save to new folder.Tell me how to do that.
This is the Sample code given at libtiff.net.Link https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/html/91d736ff-8648-4c2f-a87a-9d8d215416b8.htm

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic;


namespace TiffConverterApp
{
   internal class Program   {

            public static void Main()
            {

            using (Tiff tiff = Tiff.Open(@"SampleData\abc.tiff", "r"))
                {
                    int width = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH)[0].ToInt();
                    int height = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH)[0].ToInt();
                    double dpiX = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.XRESOLUTION)[0].ToDouble();
                    double dpiY = tiff.GetField(TiffTag.YRESOLUTION)[0].ToDouble();

                    byte[] scanline = new byte[tiff.ScanlineSize()];
                    ushort[] scanline16Bit = new ushort[tiff.ScanlineSize() / 2];

                    using (Tiff output = Tiff.Open("processed.tif", "w"))
                    {
                        if (output == null)
                            return;

                        output.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH, width);
                        output.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH, height);
                        output.SetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, 16);
                        output.SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
                        output.SetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, Photometric.MINISBLACK);
                        output.SetField(TiffTag.PLANARCONFIG, PlanarConfig.CONTIG);
                        output.SetField(TiffTag.ROWSPERSTRIP, 1);
                        output.SetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION, Compression.LZW);

                        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
                        {
                            tiff.ReadScanline(scanline, i);
                            MultiplyScanLineAs16BitSamples(scanline, scanline16Bit, 16);
                            output.WriteScanline(scanline, i);

                        }
                    }

                    Process.Start("processed.tif");
                }
            }

            private static void MultiplyScanLineAs16BitSamples(byte[] scanline, ushort[] temp, ushort factor)
            {
                if (scanline.Length % 2 != 0)
                {
                    // each two bytes define one sample so there should be even number of bytes
                    throw new ArgumentException();
                }

                // pack all bytes to ushorts
                Buffer.BlockCopy(scanline, 0, temp, 0, scanline.Length);

                for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
                    temp[i] *= factor;

                // unpack all ushorts to bytes
                Buffer.BlockCopy(temp, 0, scanline, 0, scanline.Length);
            }

    public static void AddToLog(string Msg)
        {
            try
            {
                string path = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["LogFilePath"];
                string TodayDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
                string LogPath = path + "\\" + TodayDate;
                if (!Directory.Exists(LogPath))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(LogPath);
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(LogPath + "\\Log.log", FileMode.Append);
                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter((Stream)fileStream);
                streamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + Msg);
                streamWriter.Close();
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Following is the stacktrace**

```
at BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Internal.LZWCodec.LZWEncode(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Int16 plane)
at BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Internal.LZWCodec.predictor_encoderow(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Int16 plane)
at BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Internal.CodecWithPredictor.EncodeRow(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Int16 plane)
at BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff.WriteScanline(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 row, Int16 plane)
at BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff.WriteScanline(Byte[] buffer, Int32 row)
at TiffConverterApp.Program.Main() in D:\TiffProject\TiffConverterApp\TiffConverterApp\Program.cs:line 52
```

Comment: So, this is example code? Not the code that causes the exception? Please show the actual code you are using and point to the line that the exception is thrown from. Btw, "*Tell me how to do that*" sounds quite rude. You might want to reformulate this.

Comment: @NicoSchertler This is the code I am using. I have pointed line that gives me the exception in my question. I am getting error 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' at line output.WriteScanline(scanline, i);